# Why does jQuery's remove() method accept a selector?

Tags: jquery

I noticed a strange thing when using `remove` from jQuery. Although jQuery cleary states that:

> **selector**
>   Type: String
>   A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed.

If you try this code:

```
$element.remove('.k-grouping-header,.k-group-cell,.k-group-col,.k-grouping-row');
```

it won't work as expected and you have to use

```
$element.find('.k-grouping-header,.k-group-cell,.k-group-col,.k-grouping-row').remove();
```

Did you guys noticed it as well or it is only me doing something wrong?
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YzfRT/

Comment: What is $element? Does it really contain .k-* elements?

Comment: have a look @jsfiddle

Comment: *"A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed."* it's all right there in the explanation. It filters the set of matched elements, it does not search for other elements. It's there for when you have a collection of elements but only want to remove certain ones out of said collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove()` will take all elements that are selected out of the DOM, whether you pass an argument or not.

Passing an argument (selection) to `remove()` will filter those elements to match that selection.

Presumably in the first instance, you have your parent selected. `remove()` would try to remove this element, but since it (probably) doesn't match `.k-grouping-header,.k-group-cell,.k-group-col,.k-grouping-row` it will stay where it is.

Your confusion probably comes from not understanding the difference between **filtering** and **finding**

Your second attempt is correct.

**Why allow a selector at all?**
Primarily for chaining. Consider you have many elements selected to call a jQuery method on, maybe you'd like to change the colour:

```
$('div').css({color:"#F00"})
```

But then you only wanted to remove the ones with the class `.remove`? You can still chain, and filter the ones to remove:

```
$('div').css({color:"#F00"}).remove('.remove')
```

Which, by the way, does exactly the same as:

```
$('div').css({color:"#F00"}).filter('.remove').remove()
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPfmT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You see, there written filtering. It means that you should choose for example in this

```
<div class="orion"></div>
<div class="orion"></div>
<div class="omega"></div>
```

so you should write

```
$('div').remove('.orion');
```

Because it's filtering classes from each chosen elements, but it doesn't work like $('body').remove('orion'), something like $('body').find('.orion').remove();

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The argument inside the `.remove()` function is used as a filter to the selector,

So,

`$('div').remove('.abc')`

will remove `<div>`s with class `abc`, not its children with class `abc`.

---

In your case,use

```
$('p',$element).remove('.k-grouping-header,.k-group-cell,.k-group-col,.k-grouping-row');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YzfRT/3/)**